# Replace specific values in a matrix using Python

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, classification, sparse-matrix

I have a m x n matrix where each row is a sample and each column is a class. Each row contains the soft-max probabilities of each class. I want to replace the maximum value in each row with 1 and others with 0. How can I do it efficiently in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best answer to your particular question is to use a matrix type object.

A sparse matrix should be the most performant in terms of storing large numbers of these matrices of large sizes in a memory friendly way, given that most of the matrix is populated with zeroes. This should be superior to using numpy arrays directly especially for very large matrices in both dimensions, if not in terms of speed of computation, in terms of memory.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy       #older versions may require `import scipy.sparse`

matrix = np.matrix(np.random.randn(10, 5))
maxes = matrix.argmax(axis=1).A1           
                      # was .A[:,0], slightly faster, but .A1 seems more readable
n_rows = len(matrix)  # could do matrix.shape[0], but that's slower
data = np.ones(n_rows)
row = np.arange(n_rows)
sparse_matrix = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix((data, (row, maxes)), 
                                        shape=matrix.shape, 
                                        dtype=np.int8)
```

This sparse_matrix object should be very lightweight relative to a regular matrix object, which would needlessly track each and every zero in it. To materialize it as a normal matrix:

```
sparse_matrix.todense()
```

returns:

```
matrix([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=int8)
```

Which we can compare to `matrix`:

```
matrix([[ 1.41049496,  0.24737968, -0.70849012,  0.24794031,  1.9231408 ],
        [-0.08323096, -0.32134873,  2.14154425, -1.30430663,  0.64934781],
        [ 0.56249379,  0.07851507,  0.63024234, -0.38683508, -1.75887624],
        [-0.41063182,  0.15657594,  0.11175805,  0.37646245,  1.58261556],
        [ 1.10421356, -0.26151637,  0.64442885, -1.23544526, -0.91119517],
        [ 0.51384883,  1.5901419 ,  1.92496778, -1.23541699,  1.00231508],
        [-2.42759787, -0.23592018, -0.33534536,  0.17577329, -1.14793293],
        [-0.06051458,  1.24004714,  1.23588228, -0.11727146, -0.02627196],
        [ 1.66071534, -0.07734444,  1.40305686, -1.02098911, -1.10752638],
        [ 0.12466003, -1.60874191,  1.81127175,  2.26257234, -1.26008476]])
```

Comment: It's really great in term of memory usage! Thank you so much :-)

Comment: @Matrix thanks for the great question, I've really gotten a lot out of answering it. Keep it up.

Answer (score 2):

Some made up data:

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(5, 5)
>>> a
array([[ 0.06922196,  0.66444783,  0.2582146 ,  0.03886282,  0.75403153],
       [ 0.74530361,  0.36357237,  0.3689877 ,  0.71927017,  0.55944165],
       [ 0.84674582,  0.2834574 ,  0.11472191,  0.29572721,  0.03846353],
       [ 0.10322931,  0.90932896,  0.03913152,  0.50660894,  0.45083403],
       [ 0.55196367,  0.92418942,  0.38171512,  0.01016748,  0.04845774]])
```

In one line:

```
>>> (a == a.max(axis=1)[:, None]).astype(int)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

A more efficient (and verbose) approach:

```
>>> b = np.zeros_like(a, dtype=int)
>>> b[np.arange(a.shape[0]), np.argmax(a, axis=1)] = 1
>>> b
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Good answer, plus one.

Answer (score 0):

This approach using basic numpy and list comprehensions works, but is the least performant. I'm leaving this answer here as it may be somewhat instructive. First we create a numpy matrix:

```
matrix = np.matrix(np.random.randn(2,2))
```

`matrix` is, e.g.:

```
matrix([[-0.84558168,  0.08836042],
        [-0.01963479,  0.35331933]])
```

Now map 1 to a new matrix if the element is max, else 0:

```
newmatrix = np.matrix([[1 if i == row.max() else 0 for i in row] 
                                                   for row in np.array(matrix)])
```

`newmatrix` is now:

```
matrix([[0, 1],
        [0, 1]])
```

Comment: @Matrix I was trying to come up with a better approach. Jaime currently has me beat, but I'm on to something that would be a performant alternative, which I'll reveal if/when I get it ironed out.

Answer (score 0):

```
Y = np.random.rand(10,10)
X=np.zeros ((5,5))
y_insert=2
x_insert=3
offset = (1,2)
for index_x, row in enumerate(X):
  for index_y, e in enumerate(row):
    Y[index_x + offset[0]][index_y + offset[1]] = e
```